# Azure Devops Release Pipeline Json File Transformation Not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a release pipeline in Azure Devops, and want to replace some settings in the appsettings.json files. I have this pipeline:

[image]

If I inspect this zip on my build server, the root of the zip file contains 2 appsettings files, one called `appsettings.json` and another one `appsettings.Production.json`. Inside the root of both of them is this key:

```
"ElasticApm": { "ServerUrl": "blabla" }
```

I want to replace `blabla` with something else in both files. My pipeline variable looks like this:

[image]

However, when I run the release pipeline, and check the json files on the IIS server, the variable isn't replaced. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. I just set the file transformation step to target `**\appsettings*` and it works. Also if you’re targeting something in an array, remember that they start counting at zero…